# Copy Some Column Into Another Table And Insert New Values in the same SQL statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, insert

I have a `Car` table with columns `carID, brand, color, price`.  I want to only copy `color` to another table `Detail` which have columns `finish, color`.  And the `Finish` column is not `NULL`.

Is it possible to copy `Color` from `Car` table into my `Details` table at the same time (in the same SQL statement) while inserting a value for `Finish` (value will be given by the user)?

My Prepared Statement is:

```
String finish = request.getParameter("finish") //get user input from form
int carID = ... //retrieved from another SQL statement

public void insertToDetail(int carID, String finish){

     String sql = "INSERT INTO detail (finish, color) VALUES ?, "
      + "SELECT color FROM car WHERE carID = ? ;";

     PreparedStatement psmt = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

     psmt.setString(1, finish);
     psmt.setInt(2, carID);
     psmt.executeUpdate();  
     psmt.close();

}
```

A case scenario would be for example:

My `Car` table has the values (`001`, `Nissan`, `red`, `14500`) and the user inputs `gloss` for `finish` from my form.

Once the user press the `submit` button, the end result should be the `Detail` table having the values `(gloss, red)` with `gloss` coming from user input and `red` being copied from `Car` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not really tell us what is the issue that your are having...

But anyway, this :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO detail (color, finish) VALUES ?, "
  + "SELECT FROM car (color) WHERE carID = ? ;";
```

Should be :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO detail SELECT ?, color FROM car WHERE carID = ?;";
```

The remaining of your code should not need to be changeed.

Comment: I'm just confused if I have multiple `?` marks, do they each go in order of when they appear?  For example, the first `?` in `..detail SELECT ?, ...` would be referring to `pmst.setString(finish)`?

Comment: Also `finish` does not appear in my `Car` table.  It's only on my `Detail` table.

Comment: @JamesMcTyre : yes, `?` go in the order in which they appear in the query. So you do assign `finish` as first bind variable, and the value your provide  will go directly in the `detail` table. Meanwhile, the second bind variable will be used to search the `car` table and the resulting `color` will be used to feed the other column of the new `detail` record

Comment: Does that mean that `SELECT ?, color FROM car....` that since `?` is binded to `finish`, the actual `finish` column does not have to be in the same table of `Car`?  Because I've been reading it as `SELECT finish, color FROM car` and thought that `finish` has to be a column in the `Car` table...

Comment: yes ; the value of `finish` is the one that you assign to the bind variable, and has nothing to do with table `car`. Meanwhile, the second bind variable is used to search `car` for a matching id, and to choose the `color`. Hope that clarify. You may also give the code a try and see what happens...

Comment: Alright.  And if for example I want to copy more columns (`brand` and `price`) into `Detail` table should I do something like `color FROM car WHERE carID = ?,  brand FROM car WHERE carID = ?, price FROM car WHERE carID = ?` or `color, brand, price FROM car WHERE carID = ?` ?

Comment: Yes if these columns also come from the `car` table, then do : `INSERT INTO detail SELECT ?, color, brand, price FROM car WHERE carID = ?`

Comment: @JamesMcTyre : got to go... If this answer was helpful, please upvote / accept it ! Thanks ! And welcome to the mysql world... Cheers